# How to add overflow icon items in a card in Android

Tags: android, cardslib

Hi I am trying to create a layout like this using support library https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html but i didn't found a way to add overflow icon in a card.

I don't want to use this library https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARDGRID.md. I want to do same using support library that Google introduced recently.

Isn't there is way to achieve using support library or I have to use gabrielemariotti library to add overflow items in a card view.

[image]

### Update

Guys I have edited question now it is more clear what i want.

Comment: "i didn't found a way to do so" -- what did you try? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried to see post on internet but didn't find anything to do using support lib

Comment: Did you use a `CardView` as the container around your cell content in your `Adapter` for your `GridView`? If not, why are you asking here before even trying it yourself?

Comment: @CommonsWare no you didn't get my question. My Question was not to use card view using grid. I wanted to ask how to make views such like there is arrow at the bottom, on click on it user can install that app

Comment: "My Question was not to use card view using grid" -- the title of your question is "How to create card grid view layout". "how to make views such like there is arrow at the bottom" -- there is no arrow in the screenshot.

Comment: @CommonsWare see at the bottom in the red rectangle there is overflow icon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all **you shouldn't use** this lib **only to achieve** an overflow menu inside a card.

Said that,the CardView in support Library is a *FrameLayout* with any model behind.
The best way to achieve it, now is to use the new `Toolbar` inside the CardView layout.

Also you can add a `ImageView` inside the `CardView` layout and do something like this:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), mImageButton);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, popup.getMenu());
```

Finally (but it is not so important) if it isn't enough, the new cardslib (coming soon) will use the CardView in support library.

Comment: The parameters for the `inflater.inflate()` function is `R.menu.your_menu_res` which is nothing but the id of the xml menu you want to inflate, and the you need to pass `popup.getMenu()` as the 2nd paramter

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it correctly in an `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`. In my example, it's a cardview inside of a RecyclerView, so I set this up in the adapter, inside the onBindViewHolder method:

```
public class DashboardItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_dashboard, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder vh, int position) {
        final Item item = mItems.get(position);

        ...

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, vh.btnMenu);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_card_waiting);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_cancel:
                    cancelItem();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        });
        vh.btnMenu.setOnClickListener(btn -> popup.show());
    }

    ...
}
```