# Adding overflow menu item in cardlayout of android

Tags: android, menu, cardlayout

Hi I am creating small android application with cardlayout view. I have create card.Now I want to add overflow menu to my cardlayout. I can add image of overflow menu in my card layout. But how to open some overflow menu on click of it. Need some help. Thank you. I dont want to use any library because I already created UI for my cards. Just want to add overflow menu.

Comment: This should be reopened. It's a valid question for a very specific function: How to add an overflow menu to a card. I have an answer to this exact question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35166377/456568

Answer (score 3):

Try **Popup Menu** ex. http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

or **PopupWindow** ex. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html

or **ListPopupWindow** ex.http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2078060&seqNum=4

all of them will work for you. But Popup menu is good as it works like optionsMenu for android.

Answer (score 0):

ok i just got that project :)
Don't know if it was the best way or not but i had done that :p
I just simply created a listView in same layout and had set its visibility to "gone".

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/spinnerlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_upper"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_menu"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_upper"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and for this
private String menuTitle[] = { "Facebook Login", "About", "Setting" };

then i set menuAdapter:

```
private class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return menuTitle.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.item_menu, null);
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_menuitem))
                .setText(menuTitle[arg0]);
        return v;
    }

}
```

and finally hide and seek ;)

```
iv_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // lv_menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // lv_menu.setCacheColorHint(color.transparent);
            if (flag) {
                list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lv_menu.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter());
                flag = false;
            }
            else {

                list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lv_menu.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter());
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    });
    lv_menu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            lv_menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //you code for doing Actions
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Kiturk thank you for quick replay. But I have already created card view. Just want overflow menu like in action bar with 3 dots. In same way s google showing in google play cards.

Comment: ohh okok i have done before... lemme have a look and will get back to you soon